# Comment se passe la permission au tutoiement typiquement

Tags: tutoiement

Il me semble que le tutoiement est similaire au "first-name basis" en Anglais. On passe au "first-name basis" quand on dit quelque chose comme "please call me Mark". On français, comment on passe au tutoiement typiquement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Une façon simple et courante de passer au tutoiement est de demander :

> On peut se tutoyer ?

ou de suggérer:

> On peut se tutoyer / On pourrait se tutoyer.

Sauf si on fait partie d'un groupe où c'est l'usage (enfants, étudiants, famille, membres d'un club, d'une association, d'un parti politique, discussions dans un forum ou sur Internet en général) on évite de tutoyer d'office quelqu'un en France métropolitaine. La situation peut être différente au Québec, en Afrique ou outremer.

Mieux vaut donc éviter :

> Ça [ne] **te** dérange pas que je **te** tutoie / qu'on se tutoie ?

Answer (score 2):

À en croire des spécialistes, le passage du vouvoiement au tutoiement est une affaire délicate; je dirais personnellement qu'il en est ainsi pour des personnes de sensibilité élevée. L'entrée en matière à un [article intéressant à ce sujet](https://www.capital.fr/votre-carriere/quand-passer-du-vous-au-tu-615110) (recopiée ci-dessous) commence à situer le problème, qui en réalité n'a pas vraiment d'aspect unique.

> L’anecdote est célèbre. A un militant qui lui demandait «Je peux te tutoyer ?», François Mit­­terrand, alors premier secrétaire du PS¹, avait lâché un glacial « Si vous voulez ». Quel est le bon moment pour sauter le pas ? Et comment choisir les mots ? Avec un collègue, un supérieur ou un client, passer du vouvoiement au tutoiement est un exer­cice délicat. Selon l’ethnologue Denis Guigo, auteur d’une étude sociologique chez Peugeot, il existe trois barrières implicites au tutoie­ment : les différences d’âge, de sexe et de niveau hiérarchique.
> ¹<sub>Parti Socialiste</sub>

Entre personnes qui ne se posent pas de questions, que l'activité intellectuelle ne stimule pas, et pour les personnes un peu simples et/ou un peu rudes  il n'y a pas de façon bien compliquée de passer du « vous » au « tu » : souvent, l'une des deux commence à utiliser la seconde personne du singulier et l'autre fait alors de même.
([français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11009.php)) Dans les régions du sud de la France, […], dire "tu" dès la première rencontre est beaucoup plus fréquent que dans le nord, où souvent le tutoiement spontané peut être ressenti comme une agression.

*Entre collègues, quelques variantes sur un même « thème »*

[réf.](https://www.capital.fr/votre-carriere/quand-passer-du-vous-au-tu-615110)

- Nous pour­rions peut-être nous tutoyer ?
- Je ne me souviens plus : on se tutoie ou on se vouvoie ? (*Vous n’avez pas vu la personne depuis quelque temps ; personnellement je déconseille cette solution de facilité : une personne sensible ne manquera pas de détecter le mensonge et vous avez toutes les chances de passer pour un renard.*)

[Quora, Rodrigue Chamna](https://fr.quora.com/Comment-passer-%C3%A9l%C3%A9gamment-du-vouvoiement-au-tutoiement)

- Ça ne me gênerais pas si vous me tutoyez.  (*Demande polie ; il est clair qu'en cas de réponse positive vous aussi pouvez tutoyer.*)
- Ça vous gênerait que je vous tutoie ? (*Demande polie*)
- Je me sentirais plus détendu si on se tutoyais. (*Si le vouvoiement vous met mal à l'aise, mais pas très polie puisque cette demande est une façon de forcer la main de la personne à qui vous vous adressez.*)

[français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11009.php)

- On pourrait se tutoyer maintenant, ce serait plus simple ? (*Demande pas trop polie puisqu'elle insinue que la personne à qui l'on parle rend les choses compliquées en utilisant « vous » (ce qui n'est pas vrai).*)
- Ça vous dérangerait si on se tutoyait ? (*Demande  polie*)
- On pourrait peut-être se dire « tu » ? (*Demande  polie*)

Toutes sortes de variantes sur les modèles ci-dessus sont possibles, par exemple en utilisant « arrêter de se vouvoyer » et  « arrêter de se dire « vous ».

Comment: *toutes les chances de passer pour un renard* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Eh bien, oui, si quelqu'un s'aperçoit que l'on n'est pas sincère et que l'on prétend des histoires dans le seul but d'obtenir quelque chose d'eux ils vont nous juger comme étant plutôt malhonnêtes;  par exemple,  le renard de La Fontaine  ne monte pas dans l'arbre pour restituer son fromage au corbeau…pour le moins qu'on puisse dire…

Comment: J'apprécie la mention préléminaire, je trouve toujours cela assez délicat... Dans un sens comme dans l'autre d'ailleurs, certaines personnes n'appréciant pas non plus d'être vouvoyées, d'autres ayant du mal à tutoyer. Je n'arrive par exemple pas à tutoyer mes beaux-parents, mais je trouverais très étrange qu'eux-mêmes me vouvoient.

Comment: @20goto10 C. − P. anal. (d'attitude)
1.
a) Parfois péj. Homme rusé, parfois perfide, fourbe. Fin, vieux renard. Ce n'était qu'un filou parmi des brigands, un renard dans une bande de loups (Gautier,Fracasse, 1863, p. 75).Tu es fin, sagace, un vrai renard (Bernanos,Joie, 1929, p. 651).V. lion ex. de Lemaitre, loup ex. de Rolland.